# How to get the Name of a logged in User on a Website

Tags: php, html

If the user is logged in i want that the name of the user is shown in the navbar like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRP4R.png

I have one login.php page which refers (with a successfull login) to my Loggedin.php. On this Loggedin page i start a new session and type

```
($_SESSION['username']) echo $username;
```

Which would look like this with html:

```
    <a class="right" href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <?php ($_SESSION['username']) echo $username; ?></a>
```

I know that i maybe dont get the session from the loginpage but i couldnt find a solution for this.

For more information:

login.php:

```
 <?php  
session_start();
require('../includes/connect_to_db.php');


if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{

$fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("Location: Loggedin.php");
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}else{

}

?>
```

And here is what i tryed on the loggedin.php page:

```
<?php
//Start Session
session_start();
//Connect to db
require('../includes/connect_to_db.php'); 
//echo the username
 echo $_SESSION['username'];

?>
```

and the echo i implement to the navbar with the already shown html/php code:

```
<a class="right" href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <?php ($_SESSION['username']) echo $username; ?></a>
```

Comment: Another remark: please think about securing your passwords. Using the provided code, the passwords are stored in plaintext in your database.

Answer (score -1):

If the username is stored in the session, you should output that value:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: But he did not say that it's not working, and all real examples in the code show the strange code `($_SESSION['username']) echo $username;` which does not look like he really tried to echo a value from the session...

Comment: The Problem is that i cant get the username from the session of the login page. I type in the user credentials on the loginpage and when the credentials are correct it refers to the loggedin page on this page i start a new session to try to get them there someway cause i dont know how to get the session from the loginpage. I tryed something which is showed above.

Comment: Maybe i can somehow save the username like : $_SESSION['username'] = $variableStoringUsername; and output it in the loggedin page?

Comment: And you see in my post at the end that i tryed that too didnt worked too @NicoHaase

Comment: So, to recap: you want to get a value from the session, you are using `$_SESSION['username']` everywhere you want to output the username, but that does not work yet? Is it properly written to the session? According to the provided code, you only write the username to the session if the login is successful

Comment: I fixed it with: 
require('PHP/loginscript.php'); with that i could access the username cause it was written in that session